# d3.json getting 'Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list'

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to follow a d3 tutorial that uses v4. I had problems with the callback and discovered that this had changed in v5, so I updated it to the code seen below. I believe I have followed the syntax in the d3 documentation verbatim. In vsCode I am getting this syntax error on lines 21 and 22 at any punctuation: ',' expected. But in localhost through live server I get: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list' app.js:21. I have tried adding, removing semicolons. I tried replacing the referenced function, 'type', with a placeholder function (just a console.log) to eliminate the possibility of syntax errors in that. I have npm installed d3 to make sure it is up to date. In case it is relevant, the point of the function is to modify parts of the data (parsing string to number, string to js date obj) before logging it to the console.

```
const parseDate = string => d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d')(string);

function type(d) {
    return {
        recordId: +d.recordId,
        dataDate: parseDate(d.dataDate),
        unitName: d.unitName,
        unitId: d.unitId,
        type: d.type,
    }
};

d3.json("http://localhost:3000/records").then(type(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I have also tried:

```
let newData=
d3.json("http://localhost:3000/records")
.then((d) => {
    type(d)
    console.log(d)
});

console.log(newData);
```

This results in no syntax errors and the console.log(d) displays the un-parsed data, but console.log(newData) only seems to return a promise.

I am a newbie so if you are able to answer my question, please explain it to me like I'm 5, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`d3.json()` does expect a `.json` file so make sure to replace your URL accordingly. Then, to get your data, you need a function so replace your Promise as follow:

```
d3.json("http://localhost:3000/records.json").then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

To format your data, the best way is to do it within the `d3.json()` method. Try this:

```
const dataset = d3.json("http://localhost:3000/records.json", d => {    
  return {      
    recordId: +d.recordId,         
    dataDate: parseDate(d.dataDate),         
    unitName: d.unitName,         
    unitId: d.unitId,         
    type: d.type,   
  } 
});    

dataset.then(function(data) { 
  console.log(data); 
});
```

You will find additional examples in the [d3.js documentation for d3-fetch](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/v2.0.0/README.md#json)

Comment: Thank you! I tried 'function' instead of 'type' and it does indeed fix the syntax errors! However, now I can't route my data through the 'type' function above, which parses some of the object properties for me. This was why I had 'type' in there to begin with. In this case, I am calling a mock API that I built rather than a file, so that's why it doesn't have '.json'. The call does seem to work and it logs my array of json objects to the console fine without it. It just doesn't run the 'type' function to parse the data

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I was starting to see that it had something to do with the promise being returned, not the data. I tried your suggestion and I am getting the data logged to the console, but it is still failing to parse anything; it is just returning the json exactly as it comes from the api

Comment: You should have now an array of objects. Doing `data[0].recordId` should give you the first recordId as a number (because you parsed it as a number) and `data[0].dataDate` should give you the first dataDate the way your parsed it in your function. Can you confirm?

Comment: The array of objects is coming through, but the objects appear unchanged and the properties unparsed. I added console.log(data[0].recordId/dataDate) right after the console.log(data) that appears in your suggested solution. They still return the string versions. As an additional test, I added a new property 'newThing: 12'  to the object after 'type: d.type' but this does not get added to any of the objects.

Comment: `d3.json()` does expect a `.json` file extension then. You should find a way fetch your data as a `.json` file for sure. I'm editing the answer back again. Try with a json file first and please confirm

Comment: If the path is correct then it should work.

Comment: Ok, this is what I now have: ```const dataset = d3.json("data/mockdata.json", d => {    
  return {      
    recordId: +d.recordId,         
    dataDate: parseDate(d.dataDate),         
    etc...   
  } 
});    

dataset.then(function(data) { 
  console.log(data); 
  console.log(data[0].recordId);
 console.log(data[0].dataDate);
}); 
```
It is logging the full array (still unparsed), but then after that I get: 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'recordId' of undefined
    at app.js:54',  referring to the line of the console.log(data[0].recordId);

Comment: That's because your data was not parsed successfully. Can you check that your `.json` file is valid with a JSON validator? eg: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Shoot, sorry for the formatting. I'm new to this. Basically, I did what you suggested and changed to a .json file. And tried the 3 console.logs. The first one logs the full array, but then I get the error: 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'recordId' of undefined
    at app.js:54'

Comment: As mentioned right above, make sure your JSON is valid: https://jsonlint.com. Let me know

Comment: I tried the validator and got 'valid json'

Comment: WHat do you get when you do: `d3.json("data/mockdata.json").then(function(data) { console.log(data) });` only, without the above parsing. Do you get a parsed array?

Comment: With that exact code I get a 404. If I use the same code I had above in my last long comment, but get rid of the parsing attempts: '+' or 'parseDate', I still get the same error as with them: 
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'recordId' of undefined
    at app.js:55

Comment: 404 is because the file was not found. What I would do it: try with the last message to get your data without the parsing, as an array with elements and display them in the console: `console.log(data[0])`. Finally, make sure your input file is formatted the right way: **as an array of objects**

Comment: `[{
 "recordId": 1,
 "unitName": "test"
}, {
 "recordId": 2,
 "unitName": "test2"
}]`

Comment: sincere apologies!:  d3.json("data/mockdata.json").then(function(data) { console.log(data) });   DID work, had a problem with the save. It returns the full array of unparsed objects. So the call works, just still have to figure out the parse

Comment: And still get 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'recordId' of undefined'  in response to console.log(data[0])

Comment: Oh man... I feel bad. I double checked my .json format and it still had the array 'label' from the mock API I copied it out of. So it was {"records" :  [{ etc..   That fixed the data[0].recordId, etc. coming back.  Thanks for making me check it again!! I'm a little surprised that having that makes it unrecognizable as json though, since that is literally how it would come back from an API, isn't it?

Comment: well, I guess it was thinking of it as the first 'object' (array) in an array of arrays and there was no second (like there was in the API) so that was confusing it. That's the good news I guess the bad is that it still doesn't parse anything but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  Thank you very much for offering so many suggestions and so much of your time. Let me know if you think of anything else and I try it! :)

Comment: All of this also works if I change back to the API call 'http://localhost:3000/records'

Comment: If your source is not a file but an API call instead, don't use `d3.json()`. Find a way to get your data out of a promise as an array of object (with `fetch` or `Axios`) and then use d3.js as you would normally do. You will have to parse the data after it has been loaded though. That being said, I think we got far away from the original question which I think I answered!